# Irreducible representations of wreath products of cyclic groups.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, wreath-product

Let $G= C_m \wr C_n$ be a wreath product of cyclic groups  $C_m$ and $C_n$.
I am interested to find all irreducible representation of $G$.

Update:
My thoughts: If I take $H:=\underbrace{C_m \times \cdots C_m}_{n \ times}$, then we know that $G=C_m \wr C_n=H  \rtimes C_n$. Also since we know every irreducible characters of cyclic group $C_m$, the irreducible characters of $H$ is known. Now for every $\psi \in {\rm Irr}(H)$, first we need to find $I_G(\psi)$, (the inertia group of $\psi$ in $G$) and then we must find $\varphi \in {\rm Irr}(I)$ that lies over $\psi$, and finally we must apply Clifford's correspondence.
I have difficulty in finding $I_G(\psi)$ and $\varphi$.

Comment: If you want help with this, then you will need to express your own thoughts on the question. What results in Representation Theory do you know that might be relevant? How about Clifford's Theorem?

Comment: @DerekHolt Please see my update.

Comment: It's complicated for general $n$, because there are some irreducible representations of degree $d$ for all divisors $d$ of $n$. If you have not done so already, then you could try the case $n$ prime first

Comment: @DerekHolt. Thank you.